# Batch: syntax error on %time% with environment variables

Tags: batch-file

I'm running a Batch script on a German Win7 environment with the following variable:

```
%date%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
```

This script works quite well from 10:00 until 23:59. Between 0:00 and 9:59 i get a Syntax error (I suppose because the time has only one digit before the ":")

Can someone help me with this?

Thx!

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799236/388389

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using this:

`set hour=%time:~0,2%
if "%hour:~0,1%" == " " set hour=0%hour:~1,1%
set min=%time:~3,2%
if "%min:~0,1%" == " " set min=0%min:~1,1%
set secs=%time:~6,2%
if "%secs:~0,1%" == " " set secs=0%secs:~1,1%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still *locale* dependent:

```
set "_datetime=%date%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%"
set "_datetime=%_datetime: =0%"
```

For *locale* **independent** solution (and yes, without `_` and `-` by then):

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in (
    'wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value'
) do @for /F "tokens=*" %%x in ("%%G") do (
    set "_datetime=%%~x"
)
set "_datetime=%_datetime:~0,14%"
goto :eof
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%%G` to retrieve the `LocalDateTime` value;
- `%%x` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned (`wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` instead of common `0x0D0A`).

See Dave Benham's *[`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)*