# Time comparision in batch file not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Basically what I'm trying to create is a script that only will run if the time is LEQ than 19:00 (7 PM), what I did so far is:

```
set myTime=%time%
set myFlag=false
if %myTime% LEQ 19:00 set myFlag=true
if myFlag=true (
*my script*
)
```

It returns this error message: "86 was not expected at this moment", (86 being the last numbers of the variable 'myTime' [14:36:11,86]. It just won't work.

I've also tried:

```
set myTime=%time%
set myFlag=false
if %myTime% LEQ 19:00:00,00 set myFlag=true
if myFlag=true (
*my script*
)
```

Both ways i get the same error message *double-digit number* not expected. Any thoughts on how to solve this? It's even possible do a time comparision on a windows batch file?

Comment: There is no (native) way in batch programming to do real timestamp comparisons. You can compare only strings and numbers; something like `19:00` or `19:00:00,00` is treated as string. However, if your time format leads to values with fixed length, you can compare them like strings to achieve the expected result. To avoid trouble with the `,` character, enclose the comparison expressions in quotation marks, like: `if "%myTime%" LEQ "19:00:00,00" `

Answer (score 1):

[Syntax: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

> **Delimiters**
>
> Delimiters separate one parameter from the next - they split the
>   command line up into words.
>
> Parameters are most often separated by spaces, but any of the
>   following are also valid delimiters:
>
> - Comma (,)
> - Semicolon (;)
> - Equals (=)
> - Space ( )
> - Tab (     )
>
> Notice that although `/` and `-` are commonly used to separate command
>   options, they are absent from the list above. This is because batch
>   file parameters are passed to CMD.exe which can accept it's own
>   parameters (which are invoked using `/` and `-` )

Next code snippet should work (see `set /?` and `if /?`):

```
set "myTime=%time%"
set "myFlag=false"
if "%myTime%" LEQ "19:00:00,00" set "myFlag=true"
if "%myFlag%"=="true" (
   echo *my script*
)
```

Note that above code snippet is locale dependent. You can try next  **locale independent** solution similar to [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31244832/3439404):

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "myTime=%%a"
set "myTime=%myTime:~8,6%"
set "myFlag=false"
if "%myTime%" LEQ "190000" set "myFlag=true"
if "%myFlag%"=="true" (
   echo *my script*
)
```

Read

- `WMIC.exe`: [Windows Management Instrumentation Command](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)
- `localdatetime`: [Win32_OperatingSystem class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx) property in [CIM_DATETIME format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237(v=vs.85).aspx)
- `set "myTime=%myTime:~8,6%"`: [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Ag=WScript.Arguments

If CDate(Ag(0)) > CDate(Ag(1)) then 
    Wscript.echo "Param 1 greater than Param 2"
    wscript.quit 0
else
    Wscript.echo "Param 1 NOT greater than Param 2"
    wscript.quit 1
End If
```

To use in batch (use any valid time/date string)

```
scriptname.vbs 7pm 8pm
If errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 echo Param 1 greater than param 2
If errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo Param 2 greater than param 1
```

Or

```
scriptname.vbs 19:00:00 20:00:00
If errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 echo Param 1 greater than param 2
If errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo Param 2 greater than param 1
```