# How do I copy all files in the current directory to a subdirectory folder named with the current date using xcopy?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that starts a server jar file, but before it runs I want it to make a copy of everything in the working directory and paste it in a new folder named with the current date and time, with the new folder outside the working directory. How do I fix this script?

```
@echo off
xcopy \ "C:\Users\my name\serverBackups\%date%" /s/e /h /z /f /l
java -Xms256M -Xms1G -d64 -jar server.jar 
pause
```

Comment: What error do you get? Besides depending on your date format (espacially the separator) you may not be able to create a folder/file with the date in it. It may contain `:` for eg. which is used to indicate a drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch: syntax error on %time% with environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241105/batch-syntax-error-on-time-with-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This batch code could be used for the task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1 delims=." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime') do set "DateTimeLocal=%%I" & goto ReformatDateTime
:ReformatDateTime
set "DateTimeFolder=%DateTimeLocal:~0,4%-%DateTimeLocal:~4,2%-%DateTimeLocal:~6,2%_%DateTimeLocal:~8,2%-%DateTimeLocal:~10,2%-%DateTimeLocal:~12,2%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe * "%USERPROFILE%\ServerBackups\%DateTimeFolder%\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y
java.exe -Xms256M -Xms1G -d64 -jar server.jar 
endlocal
```

The first command line executed by **FOR** is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime
```

This command outputs to handle **STDOUT** for example following two lines:

```
LocalDateTime
20170205125750.125000+060
```

This output is processed now by command **FOR**.

The first line is not of interest and therefore skipped because of option `skip=1`.

From the second line just the first string referenced with `tokens=1` up to the point used as string delimiter with `delims=.` is of interest as it contains the current local date and time in format `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`. The date/time string is assigned to environment variable `DateTimeLocal`.

The advantage of using `wmic OS GET LocalDateTime` is that the date/time format is independent on Windows Region and Language settings whereas the format of date string of environment variable `DATE` and format of time string of environment variable `TIME` depends on Windows Region and Language settings.

The disadvantage of using `wmic OS GET LocalDateTime` is that it takes much longer to execute this command in comparison to referencing the values of the environment variables `DATE` and `TIME`. But this disadvantage is of no problem here on running `wmic` just once per batch file execution.

The date/time string is next reformatted to `YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss` using string substitution for making date/time easier readable for a human. The folders sorted by name are automatically sorted also by date/time by using this format. But other formats like `DD.MM.YYYY hh.mm.ss` would be also possible.

So the string `20170205125750` is reformatted to `2017-02-05_12-57-50` and assigned to environment variable `DateTimeFolder`.

This reformatted date/time string is used next in the **XCOPY** command line where it is important that the target folder string ends with a backslash to make it clear for `xcopy` that the target specifies a directory and not a file.

Another solution is using additionally the `wmic` option `/VALUE`:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE
```

This option changes the output format to:

```
LocalDateTime=20170205125750.125000+060
```

This makes it possible to simplify the batch code a little bit:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "DateTimeLocal=%%I"
set "DateTimeFolder=%DateTimeLocal:~0,4%-%DateTimeLocal:~4,2%-%DateTimeLocal:~6,2%_%DateTimeLocal:~8,2%-%DateTimeLocal:~10,2%-%DateTimeLocal:~12,2%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe * "%USERPROFILE%\ServerBackups\%DateTimeFolder%\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y
java.exe -Xms256M -Xms1G -d64 -jar server.jar 
endlocal
```

Here is also an example using the environment variables `DATE` and `TIME` expecting date and time in format for German countries which means `DATE` is using the format `DD.MM.YYYY` and `TIME` is using the format `hh:mm:ss,xx` using 24 hours format and leading zeros for day, month, hour, minute and second smaller than 10 which means for the date/time example above `05.02.2017` for `DATE` and `12:57:50.12` for `TIME`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "DateTimeFolder=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~-7,2%-%DATE:~-10,2%_%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%-%TIME:~6,2%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe * "%USERPROFILE%\ServerBackups\%DateTimeFolder%\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y >nul
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic OS /?`
- `wmic OS GET /?`
- `xcopy /?`